# My Pi seems to be duplicating my USB stick in the file manager

Tags: usb, linux, raspbian-jessie, filesystem, storage

I formatted my USB stick and called it STORE-1
But after some time, File Manager showed me this:

[image]

Before it was SETTINGS and STORE-1. Now access is denied to STORE-11 and STORE-1 and I can only use STORE-12.

What is happening here?